# Azure Devops - Custom State added to "Completed" Category is not being recognized as "Completed"

Tags: azure-devops

I created an inherited process from the Agile Process and created a Custom State on the User Story WIT called "Done" under the "Completed" Category. This effectively hid the existing "Closed" state since you can only have one "Completed" State.

However, wherever the system is looking for "Completed", it's not recognizing "Done" as completed.

Example:

- In the backlog view, when I use the toggle for "Show/Hide Completed Work Items" to hide everything that's completed, everything that's in "Done" state is still showing.

Answer (score 0):

Backlogs are designed to display work that corresponds to a Proposed, In Progress, or Resolved category state. Once you've completed work and its state enters a Done, or Closed state, then it falls off the backlog view. You can always [create a query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) to view completed work, or view the [Recently completed pivot from the Work Items page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/view-add-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

**Show/Hide Completed child Items** is use for the child items based on current work item.

See the following example : in the backlog, I want to see Features, which means all the features in this backlog will list here except features with complete state.

Then, enable the **complete child items**, it will show feature's complete child work item instead of complete features. Also, when enable the **parents** filter, the parent epic of feature will shows up as well.

[image]

When disable the **complete child items**, both the of child items user story and task won't show up.

[image]

In addition, if the task is not complete but user story is done, user story will show up as well because the task is an uncomplete child work item.

[image]